# AJAX from Phonegap not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, cordova, phonegap-cli

This is my code in index.js:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    data: {registrationdata: registrationDataJson},
    async: false,
    url: 'https://example.com/push_reg',
    success: function(data){
        alert("Your device has been successfully registered for push notifications with device id of: " + data);
    },
    error: function(){
        alert('There was an error registering your device');
    }
});
```

I have tried it with both async on and async off.  I do not get any alert from either success or error.  I put a log line first thing where `/push_reg` routes.  If I hit it in a desktop browser it logs but not from the app.  I have `alert(registrationDataJson);` right before this code block (`registrationDataJson` is a stringified JSON) so I know the data is good.  I have `alert('after');` directly after this code block that I never hit so I know that it never gets past this block.

Comment: It should be `success` not `done`

Comment: You should elaborate on "not working." Is the fail function firing? Are there errors in the console? Are you getting an error code in the network tab? Is the code getting jammed by code before it? Also, don't set async to false. Not a good practice in javascript.

Comment: @MaxBaldwin - edited question.

Comment: what does your console say?'

Comment: @OliverQueen - since I'm working with push notifications and saving the device registration data I'm actually testing on a device.

Comment: You should read this post. It looks like you are just having cross domain issues. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19003025/phonegap-cross-domain-ajax-post-request-not-working-on-android

Comment: can you show us the config.xml file?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to elaborate and indicate what error messages code / errors you are seeing.  Check your config for  setting, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your config.xml file and make sure that you have these:

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" source="npm" spec="1.1.0" />
<allow-navigation href="*" />
<allow-intent href="*" />
<access origin="*" />

<preference name="permissions" value="none"/>
```